# Finding un-tagged text with Jsoup

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I searched for an answer on my dilemma but have come up short thus far - with no obvious solutions in my results (and I've spent quite a bit of time trying suggestions in various posts that seemed semi-related). Ok, now to the meat:

I've got a snippet of html that I'd like to get some text from - but the problem is, the text doesn't appear to have a tag (and it's not a 100% occurrence - under certain understood circumstances does the text not have a tag) Example html below:

```
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
   &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; : . . 
  <a href="?act=Q&amp;ID=249629586" target="R"><b>Post title that I have removed</b></a> &lt; 
  <span class="hnd anon">PosterHandleIReplaced</span> &gt; 
  <font size="1">06/15 11:41&nbsp;&nbsp;</font>
 </body>
</html>
```

So, the portion of text that I want to grab is between `<body>` and `<a href>`, here:

```
   &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; : . .
```

But I'm not seeing a way to grab *only* that text. When I try to convert the document or element to text, it ends up converting the entire html block into a string and returning me that, which is not what I want. I suppose I could take that entire string and start parsing it out - but that seems like it would be ridiculously error prone - not to mention the : . . part can actually be longer - depending on where the response in the thread is located (if it's buried in the thread, it could look like : . . : . . : . . : . . etc).

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jsoup stores text in TextNodes -- given an Element (in your example, the `body` element), you can call [`e.textNodes()`](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#textNodes%28%29) to get a list of its text nodes.  In this case, you're going to look at the first item in the list.  There's a small example in the `textNodes` documentation showing how that method relates to other child-getter methods, which may be helpful in more complicated tasks.

Comment: This is precisely what I ended up doing - thanks for pointing this out. If I had reputation, I would vote you up.

Comment: I get 15 rep for having the accepted answer, but you can always come back later to upvote.